# Syntax error when try to run python scripts in cmd (Windows 10)

Tags: python, cmd, syntax-error, command-prompt

I just start learning python programming. I wrote a simple program in python 3.8.2:

```
x = "Hi world"
print (x)
```

Code was saved in a python file named 'file.py'. It ran correctly in python. The problem is when try to run the same chunk of code in the command line of windows 10.

After cmd was opened, i set the path at the directory where the file is saved, in this case, my desktop. Then i tried to run the next command:

```
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop>python file.py
```

The program was not work. Windows shows me the following message:

**File "file.py", line 1
    Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

I will appreciate all your help.

Comment: remove the >>> from your file

Comment: Please add the content of your file.py to your question (copy & paste). Likely you aren't using the normal `"` in your code. (Just to be sure, I'm assuming you aren't using these `>>>` in your file.py?)

Comment: Sorry. It is edited now ;)

Answer (score 1):

If file.py just contained:

```
x = "Hi world"
print (x)
```

then that is fine but you have:

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
```

as your first line.

This is most likely as it is imported from the default python IDLE